# How to convert Excel data into mysql without installing the plugin

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

I have an Excel file which contains details about a database with 8 columns & 8000 rows.This data should be converted in to MySql. **I would like to use python but not sure which library would support this conversion.** The file which I have is Xls.I want a .sql file conversion. Could anyone help me with the python code/suggest any other alternative???

Comment: Have you considered loading the csv file directly into the MySQL database using `LOAD DATA INFILE...`?

Comment: Does it have to be the old xls, can't you convert it to csv or xlsx?

Comment: The csv file didn't work. I don't know why. I don't even get any error. I can convert xls to xlsx using Excel 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert an Excel file to an SQL file python is one of the best options. There is an **xlrd** library. The following is used to load the Excel file.

```html
import xlrd
book = xlrd.open_workbook("<file_name>")
sheet = book.sheet_by_name("<sheet_Name>")
database = MySQLdb.connect (host="localhost", user = "root", passwd = "<Password>", db = "<db_name>")
```